# Any advises where to add Google custom search engine code

Tags: php, search, google-search

I am planning to add google custom search engine in my site and I know that I have to add the provided code in my search.php file. I have tried to do it but I get errors !! anybody can help please where to add the code in the php file provided :

```
<?php $mts_options = get_option('point'); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="page" class="home-page">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="article">
            <h1 class="postsby">
                <span><?php _e("Search Results for:", "mythemeshop"); ?></span> <?php the_search_query(); ?>
            </h1>   
            <?php  $j=0; $i =0; if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <article class="<?php echo 'pexcerpt'.$i++?> post excerpt <?php echo (++$j % 2 == 0) ? 'last' : ''; ?>">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="nofollow" id="featured-thumbnail">
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?> 
                            <?php echo '<div class="featured-thumbnail">'; the_post_thumbnail('featured',array('title' => '')); echo '</div>'; ?>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <div class="featured-thumbnail">
                                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/nothumb.png" class="attachment-featured wp-post-image" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <div class="featured-cat"><?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?></div>
                    </a>
                    <header>                        
                        <h2 class="title">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        </h2>
                        <div class="post-info"><span class="theauthor"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span> | <span class="thetime"><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></span></div>

                    </header><!--.header-->
                    <div class="post-content image-caption-format-1">
                        <p>
                            <?php echo mts_excerpt(29);?>
                            <span class="readMore"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="nofollow"><?php _e('Read More','mythemeshop'); ?></a></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <div class="no-results">
                    <h5><?php _e('No Results found. We apologize for any inconvenience, please hit back on your browser or use the search form below.', 'mythemeshop'); ?></h5>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!--noResults-->
            <?php endif; ?> 
            <!--Start Pagination-->
            <?php if ( isset($mts_options['mts_pagenavigation']) && $mts_options['mts_pagenavigation'] == '1' ) { ?>
                <?php  $additional_loop = 0; global $additional_loop; mts_pagination($additional_loop['max_num_pages']); ?>           
            <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="pagination">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '&larr; '.'Older posts', 'mythemeshop' ) ); ?></li>
                        <li class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts'.' &rarr;', 'mythemeshop' ) ); ?></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <?php } wp_reset_query(); ?>
            <!--End Pagination-->           
        </div>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

regards !!

Comment: Right, what errors do you get? You need to show us what's happening. And please tidy up your code, removing anything that's not relevant.

Comment: yeaa !! :) I am not that good in php, and this file is from a theme I downloaded ... I saw a tip of removing the code between the (if (have_posts())) and the (<?php endif; ?>) and add the google code in its place, and I got the "parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (t_endif)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to change where to add the code and here is the full code of search.php

```
<?php $mts_options = get_option('point'); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="page" class="home-page">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="article">
            <h1 class="postsby">
                <span><?php _e("Search Results for:", "mythemeshop"); ?></span> <?php the_search_query(); ?>
            </h1>   
            <?php  $j=0; $i =0; if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '000306723311332550300:tfoukb5efrq';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
</div>
                </article>
            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <div class="no-results">
                    <h5><?php _e('No Results found. We apologize for any inconvenience, please hit back on your browser or use the search form below.', 'mythemeshop'); ?></h5>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!--noResults-->
            <?php endif; ?> 
            <!--Start Pagination-->
            <?php if ( isset($mts_options['mts_pagenavigation']) && $mts_options['mts_pagenavigation'] == '1' ) { ?>
                <?php  $additional_loop = 0; global $additional_loop; mts_pagination($additional_loop['max_num_pages']); ?>           
            <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="pagination">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '&larr; '.'Older posts', 'mythemeshop' ) ); ?></li>
                        <li class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts'.' &rarr;', 'mythemeshop' ) ); ?></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <?php } wp_reset_query(); ?>
            <!--End Pagination-->           
        </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```